# Queue not sorted correctly in Java

Tags: java, oop, linked-list

I am trying to write a priority queue.For my enqueue method , my logic is:

If the list is empty ,then add the transaction to the first node in the linked list

If the list is not empty , compare the time value of the transaction object in the list
with the current object , if the time of object is greater than objects in the linked list,then insert the object to the current index.

Else, just add them to the last element of the linkedlist

```
   public void enqueue(TransactionDetails elem){
        //check whether list is empty
        if (list.isEmpty()){
            list.addFirst(elem);
            return;
        }

        //queue it according to priority
        boolean positioned = false;
        for (int x = 0 ; x< list.size() ; x++){
            if ( elem.getTierTime() > list.get(x).getTierTime()){
                list.add(x , elem);
                positioned = true;
            }
        }

        if (positioned == false){
            list.addLast(elem);
        }

        
    }

   public String dequeue(){
    return list.removeFirst().getID();
   }

   public void printAll(){
    for (int x = 0 ; x< list.size() ; x++){
        System.out.println(list.get(x).toString());
    }
   }
```

I test this method by entering 4 values to the method, which I entered 2000,2000,2000,3000
accordingly.

```
        System.out.println(queue.dequeue());
        System.out.println(queue.dequeue());
        System.out.println(queue.dequeue());
        System.out.println(queue.dequeue());
```

When I tried to dequeue the list , it gives me an empty output

Instead of,

3000
2000
2000
2000

Besides , the printAll method also returned nothing.

This is my Transaction Details class.

```
public class TransactionDetails {

    private long epochTime;
    private String tier;
    private String transactionID;
    private int timeTier;

    public TransactionDetails(long time , String ID , String tier){
        this.epochTime = time;
        this.tier = tier;
        this.transactionID = ID;
        tierTimeAdvantage();
    }


    //To give the starting time of a transaction in a queue according to tier
    public void tierTimeAdvantage(){
        
        switch(this.tier){

            case "PLATINUM":
                timeTier = 3000;
                break;
            case "GOLD":
                timeTier = 2000;
                break;
            case "SILVER":
                timeTier = 1000;
                break;
            case "BRONZE" :
                timeTier = 0;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So for clarity, you are not using the core Java [java.util.PriorityQueue class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) but rather are writing your own implementation?

Comment: yeah , I m sorry for not writing clearly

Comment: You forgot to `break;` the first for loop when you have found the correct position. This means you add the item multiple times to the list. Add a `break;` after `positioned = true;`.

Comment: You can identify such problems easily yourself by using step-by-step debugging in the used Java IDE. Just place a breakpoint and execute the code in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Robert in the comment section.

```
 for (int x = 0 ; x< list.size() ; x++){
                if ( elem.getTierTime() > list.get(x).getTierTime()){
                    list.add(x , elem);
                    positioned = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

I should at a break statement to terminate the loop once I got the position.